# associativity of parentheses

Tags: associative

This msdn [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139741.aspx) says that '(' and ')' has left to right associativity.

How does that make sense? Can someone give me a example?

Comment: From the link, it appears you're using SQL Server. Is that a valid assumption? And if so, you should tag your question accordingly to provide some context.

Comment: no, I'm not using SQL server.

Comment: Then why have you looked up the SQL Server documentation? What programming language *are* you using?

Comment: I'm writing bison, so I do some search on associativity. I happen to see this, and I don't get it, so I came here to ask. Nothing specific about the program though.

Answer (score 2):

In formal grammars an operator with left-to-right precedence is left recursive.  So with binary addition:

```
S -> E
E -> E + a
E -> a
```

So the tree would look like:

```
    S
    |
    E
    |
  E + a
  |
E + a
|
a
```

As you can see the first two `a`'s are added before the second two.

For a right-associative operator, your grammar would contain right-recursion.  So with binary exponentiation:

```
S -> E
E -> a ** E
E -> a
```

Subsequently your parse tree would look like:

```
    S
    |
    E
    |
  a ** E
       |
     a ** E
          |
          a
```

As you can see the last two `a`'s are exponentiated, first, and the result of that is the power of the first `a` (this is the proper associativity for exponentiation, by the way).

For ternary and greater operators the same pattern is applied, the recursive rule is either the left-most nonterminal or the right-most nonterminal.  In the case of unary operators, though, whether or not it's left- or right-recursive depends on whether or not the nonterminal s on the left or right, respectively.  In the case of `(` `E` `)` there is a terminal on either side, and the nonterminal, although recursive, is neither left- nor right-recursive from a grammatical point of view so I think the MSDN article has *arbitrarily* declared it to be "left to right."

The associativity of parenthesis has no bearing on the fact that `d` is evaluated prior to `a+b+c` in `d+(a+b+c)` and has no bearing on the associativity of `a+b+c` as well, so I have no idea what the other Jared is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

What is unclear?  They come in a pair whenever you have a `(` you will have a `)`.  Once inside of them you work the arythmatic from left to right so if you have `d+(a+b+c)` you will do `a+b` then the sum of `a+b` added to `c` then the total sum of `a,b,c` added `d`

Comment: I am accustomed to binary operator's associativity, so I don't see they can come in a pair at first. Thanks.

Comment: Jared, Are you saying that '(' and ')' being "left to right" has any bearing on the evaluation of `a+b+c` in your example?

Comment: Only in the sense that i causes `a+b+c` to be evaluated first.